# SQL - GROUP BY and SUM using joined table fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

Let's assume there are two different tables:

PACKAGE

```
id
--
1
2
3
```

PRODUCT

```
id | package_id | currency | total
----------------------------------
1  | 1          | USD      | 100
2  | 1          | EUR      | 200
3  | 2          | USD      | 300
4  | 2          | USD      | 400
5  | 3          | GBP      | 500
```

And the desired result is to get concatenated total amounts for each package (from its products) by each DISTINCT currency, something like:

```
id | total_amount
----------------------
1  | USD 100, EUR 200
2  | USD 700
3  | GBP 500
```

Tried with this query:

```
SELECT 
packages.id,
(
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(currency,' ',total))
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                products.currency AS currency,
                SUM(products.total) AS total
            FROM products
            WHERE products.package_id = [[ packages.id ]] -- double brackets just for marking
            GROUP BY products.currency
        ) T
) AS total_amount
FROM packages
LEFT JOIN products
ON products.package_id = packages.id
GROUP BY packages.id;
```

But there is an error that **package.id** (in double brackets above) is not visible, probably because of the subquery depth.

Is there any way that it can be achieved? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try rewriting your query as a left join instead of a subquery which may be [more efficient or faster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html) as shown below:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    ct.currency_totals
FROM
    packages p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        package_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(currency,' ',total)
        ) as currency_totals
    FROM (
        SELECT
            package_id,
            currency,
            SUM(total) as total
        FROM
            products
        GROUP BY
            package_id,
            currency
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        package_id
) ct on ct.package_id=p.id;
```

| id | currency_totals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USD 100,EUR 200 |
| 2 | USD 700 |
| 3 | GBP 500 |

---

Moreover, if you only require the package id of currently used packages and no other details , using your subquery may be enough for this task.

```
SELECT
        package_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(currency,' ',total)
        ) as currency_totals
    FROM (
        SELECT
            package_id,
            currency,
            SUM(total) as total
        FROM
            products
        GROUP BY
            package_id,
            currency
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        package_id;
```

| package_id | currency_totals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USD 100,EUR 200 |
| 2 | USD 700 |
| 3 | GBP 500 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pkjQ3vHVWhyfsAg2cWQEcv/1)

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
select package_id , group_concat(concat(currency,' ',grandtotal))
from (
    select package_id,currency, sum(total) grandtotal
    from products 
    group by package_id,currency
) t group by package_id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf1df5ed990bf3e213efdda43ceb164f)*

Answer (score 0):

Try use `alias` for tables names to identify...

```
SELECT 
pkg.id,
(
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(currency,' ',total))
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                products.currency AS currency,
                SUM(products.total) AS total
            FROM products
            WHERE products.package_id =  pkg.id
            GROUP BY products.currency
        ) T
) AS total_amount
FROM packages as pkg
LEFT JOIN products
ON products.package_id = pkg.id
GROUP BY pkg.id;
```

Comment: Looks like there is the same problem with accessing the 'pkg.id' in the innermost subquery.